# Editing Python lists in a function

Tags: python, list, function

Here is the exercise I am stuck on below.

**8-10. Great Magicians**: Start with a copy of your program from Exercise 8-9. Write a function called `make_great()` that modifies the list of magicians by adding the phrase the Great to each magician’s name. Call `show_magicians()` to see that the list has actually been modified.

Here is my code from 8-9

```
def show_magicians(names):
    '''prints names of users'''

    for name in names:
    print('Hello, ' + name.title() + '!')

    magicians = ['juju', 'markie', 'taz']
    show_magicians(magicians)
```

So I get this far for 8-10:

```
def make_great():
```

But where I am confused is if the exercise wants me to insert `'the Great'` before each name in the list or if I should just make a print statement that says that, but I believe it's the former.

Comment: "modifies the list" ... "see that the list has actually been modified" - I can see how it is really difficult to see if you should actually modify the list's elements, or just print a prefix for each. :P

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about clarifying a problem statement rather than solving the problem.

Comment: It's solving by clarifying what is being asked. I am stuck because I cannot figure out how to modify the list in function_1 from function_2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the exercise wants you to add `the great` to each name but after the name. So `'taz'` becomes `'taz the great'`.

But some additional information. `magicians` is currently a local variable of the function `show_magicians` and thus cannot be modified by another function. See for example [this blog](http://www.saltycrane.com/blog/2008/01/python-variable-scope-notes/) if you don't know what I mean.

Comment: That actually makes sense and the book is normally pretty clear on these examples, but I was thrown for a loop on this one. I am just unsure of how to get the phrase added to the ending.

Comment: I think the exercise gives a hint on how to do it: *add*. But yes, you need to loop over the *global* list.